# Azure Storage Queue Exception

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am using Nuget version WindowsAzure.Storage 8.1.1 when i use the basic code to add message to storage queue.
this is the code snipe found online that i use, it fails on queue.CreateIfNotExists();

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"]);

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queueName");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a message and add it to the queue.
CloudQueueMessage couldMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(message);
queue.AddMessage(couldMessage);
```

Using Fiddler  here is my request (security has been set xxx )

```
PUT https://xxxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/queueName HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Azure-Storage/8.1.1 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.42000; Win32NT 10.0.10240.0)
x-ms-version: 2016-05-31
x-ms-client-request-id: 95a86bb9-4438-4bf4-8c42-bed8dca317f1
x-ms-date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 16:00:03 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx=
Host: xxxxxxxx.queue.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I can see the error message is:

> `InvalidResourceName`The
>   specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
>   RequestId:7b234b7d-0003-0040-3ba6-be7d43000000
>   Time:2017-04-26T16:00:04.8251125Z

Comment: Is your queue name "queueName"?

Comment: no it is locationdispatchqueue

Comment: found the problem, THANKS!! i had             CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queueName"); instead of             CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);

Comment: i guess we can't use "queueName" as an actual name of a queue?

Comment: No we can't. Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/naming-queues-and-metadata

Comment: right it's because of the capital N

Answer (score 4):

Just to close this out properly: Azure Storage Queue names must be all lower-case.

All naming conventions are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions) (a different link than provided in comments).